# How to get item from RecyclerView adapter in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In old code when I was using `ListView` with custom adapter I could get item with this code.

```
Message msg = (Message) adapter.getItem(poistion);
```

Now I am implementing `RecyclerView`. How can I get item from `RecyclerView.adapter`?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You have to implement it yourself.

Add a new method in your custom Adapter and you are done.

```
public Message getItem(int position) {
  return messageList.get(position);
}
```

Comment: Yeah of course.. but in order to have `Message` object as return value you need to set the List of items as `List<Message> mItems;` in your adapter.

Answer (score 67):

I think the correct way to `getItem()` is through `RecyclerView LayoutManager`.

```
View v = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
```

Comment: This how to get the view, not the data backing the view.

Comment: @PhoenixFF true, but if you have EditTexts as items, this is the best method to get their value (after it was changed by the user)! :)

Comment: How you get this position

Comment: How do you get the data from the view?  (assume it has a TextView named 'tv')

Comment: @johnktejik when you get the view by using above method then you can get any view attribute like 
view.textView.gettext()

Answer (score 4):

Onclicklistener did the trick

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Context context;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerviewAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager;
    String[] numbers = { "ANDROID",
            "PHP",
            "BLOGGER",
            "WORDPRESS",
            "JOOMLA",
            "ASP.NET",
            "JAVA",
            "C++",
            "MATHS",
            "HINDI",
            "ENGLISH"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativelayout1);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
        recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);

        recyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(context,numbers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerviewAdapter);



    }


    public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

        String[] numvalues;
        Context context;
        View view1;
        ViewHolder viewHolder1;
        TextView textView;



        public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context1,String[] numvalues1){
            numvalues = numvalues1;
            context = context1;


        }

        public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public TextView textView;

            public ViewHolder(View v){
                super(v);
                textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.number_textview);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,parent,false);
       //     view1.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());
            view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    int itemPosition = recyclerView.indexOfChild(v);
                    //    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Selected item position is---"+ itemPosition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.number_textview);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Selected val of clicked position is---"+ textView.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            viewHolder1 = new ViewHolder(view1);



            return viewHolder1;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView.setText(numvalues[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return numvalues.length;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In recycleview you can get items from RecyclerView adapter by using below code,

```
RecyclerView rv_list_frames;

public frames getItem(int position) {
  return rv_list_frames.get(position);
}
```

i wish above that can help you for getting items..

Comment: This will return the View but not the item.

Answer (score -5):

```
@Override public void onClick(View view, int position) {

System.out.println("cardetail_activity"+position);
 Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CarDetail.class); 
ListingDataprovider data_provider=arrayList.get(position); i.putExtra("ID",data_provider.getId()); getActivity().startActivity(i);

}
```

Comment: What in the world?