# How to get an adapter item object from a LayoutManager view (RecyclerView)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` to which I attach a `LinearLayoutManager` and a `RecyclerView.Adapter`

```
    RecyclerView conversationList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.conversationList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    conversationList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    MessagesAdapter adapter = new MessagesAdapter();
    conversationList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In `onBindViewHolder` of `RecyclerView.Adapter` I'm passing the adapter item object to the view by using setTag:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.itemView.setTag(getItem(position));
        ...
    }
```

I'm iterating over child views of the `layoutManager` and get the needed object by using the `getTag` method

```
        for (int i = 0; i < layoutManager.getChildCount(); i++) {
            LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)layoutManager.getChildAt(i);
            LinearLayout container2 = (LinearLayout)container.getChildAt(0);
            Object tag = container2.getTag();
        }
```

It doesn't seem right to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Is it not working? If it's working, but you want opinions on the code or better ways to do it, you should use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get item from RecyclerView adapter in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665418/how-to-get-item-from-recyclerview-adapter-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

when you scroll the view,the `ViewHolder` may reused, so it`s was reset. Due to this you may get a wrong tag when you want get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like that to your Adapter class:

```
public ArrayList<Objects> getAllTags(){
    ArrayList<Objects> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount() ; i++){
        arrayList.add(getItem(i));
    }
    return arrayList;
}
```

And the retrieve the objects via:

```
adapter.getAllObjects();
```

I'm assume that :

```
getItem(position)
```

Is method you defines in adapter class.